# mysql database doesn't insert any items on the table,browsers don't show any error either

Tags: php, mysql

I've fixed all the syntax errors,but items I'm trying to insert on the table are not passing on table in the database.Here is the code:

```
   <?php
   session_start();
   if(!isset($_SESSION["manager"])){
   header("location:admin_login.php");
   exit();
    }

   $id=preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["id"]);
   $manager=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["manager"]);
   $password=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["password"]);
   include "connect_to_db.php";
   $sqlcommand="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM admin WHERE id='$id' AND username='$manager'    AND      password='$password' LIMIT 1";
   $counting=mysqli_query($connect_dude,$sqlcommand);
   $numrow=mysqli_num_rows($counting);
   if($numrow==0){
   echo "you better get out of here";
   exit();
   }
   ?>
   <?php 
   // Script Error Reporting
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ?>
  <?php

     if(isset($_POST["product_name"])){

    $productname=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z]#i','',$_POST["product_name"]);
    $productprice=preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_POST["product_price"]);
    $productdetails=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_POST["product_detail"]);
    $productdivision=$_POST["product_division"];
    $productsubdivision=$_POST["product_subdivision"];
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE product_name='$productname' LIMIT 1";
    $counting=mysqli_query($connect_dude,$sql);
    $numrow=mysqli_num_rows($counting);
    if($numrow>0){
    echo "you have added the product before";
    }
    else{
    $sql="INSERT INTO products (product_name,price,details,category,subcategory,date_added) VALUES ($productname,$productprice,$productdetails,$productdivision,$productsubdivision,now())";
    mysqli_query($connect_dude,$sql);
    $pid=mysqli_insert_id();
    $newfile=$pid.jpg;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"$productsubdivision/$newfile");
    header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
       }
    }

    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
     <body>

    <fieldset>
      <legend value="add something">Add product,dude</legend>
   <form id="formo" action="inventory_list.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Product Name:<input type="text" id="product_name" name="product_name" placeholder="Type Product Name" /></br>
   Product price:<input type="text" id="product_price" name="product_price" placeholder="Type Product price" /></br>
   Product division:
  <select id="product_division" name="product_division">
    <option>select</option>
    <option>food</option>
 <option>apparel</option>
<option>beauty</option>
<option>toys</option>
   </select>
  </br> 
       Product type:
        <select id="product_subdivision" name="product_subdivision">
       <option>select</option>
          <option>Rice</option>
        <option>milk</option>
       <option>Meat</option>
       <option>sweet</option>
     <option>fruits</option>
      <option>cap</option>
      <option>shirt</option>
     <option>pant</option>
     </select>
  </br>
     Product Detail:<textarea id="product_detail" name="product_detail" placeholder="Type Product detail,bro" ></textarea> 
    </br>
    product Image:<input type="file" id="image" name="image" />
     </br>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add This Item Now" />

     </form>
  </fieldset>
  </body>
   </html>
```

showing me the message,"you have added the product before",but not inserting into the table.
I'm a beginner PHP programmer.Please help.

Comment: Have you tried `echo`ing `mysql_error()`?

Comment: @Kerry yes,I did.using "error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');"

Comment: Regular expressions are not the answer to everything. To ensure you get an integer, just use `intval($value)`. To prepare a value for insertion in a database, use `mysqli_real_escape_string($value)`. Also, your regex for product details means I can't add spaces, dashes, punctuation or anything. And passwords **never** go into a database without some hashing function like [password_hash](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: @user2943607 That is not the same thing, mysql_error() is a function. Use it: http://us3.php.net/mysql_error

Comment: add `or die(mysqli_error($connect_dude))` at the end of your `mysqli_query();` statement just before the semi-colon.

Comment: @Timmy Done that.Still not working.showing 4 notices on chrome,saying "Notice: Undefined index: product_price",Notice: Undefined index: product_detail""Notice: Undefined index: product_division and subdivision".after that echo msg "Notice: Undefined index: product_price".but no product on the table.Please help,if you can

Comment: Aye those notices are what you need to fix to get your script running.  Kai's answer and comments below along with PHP->MYSQL and HTML tutorials are in abundance on the internet so you should be able to solve your problem quite easily. The first 4 lines of the answer below address your undefined index issues.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the name attribute on your fields. `$_POST['product_name']` is not set.

```
<input type="text" id="product_name" placeholder="Type Product Name" />
```

should be

```
<input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" placeholder="Type Product Name" />
```

Your conditional is checking `isset($_POST['product_name'])` to run the insert, so because the name attribute is missing, that conditional is never evaluating to true.

Side note, you are also trying to accept a file. You need to have `enctype="miltipart/form-data"` in the form attributes:

```
<form id="formo" action="inventory_list.php" method="post" enctype="miltipart/form-data">
```

Also, make sure you have a name attribute for all fields.

You are also checking against a boolean in your count:

```
$numrow=mysqli_num_rows($counting);
if($counting==1){
```

that should be

```
$numrow=mysqli_num_rows($counting);
if($numrow > 0){
```

Comment: tried with the code you provided.Still not working.Any suggestion?

Comment: did you add name attributes to all fields? I updated though what I provided should at least get you into that conditional. You should be able to see some errors and take it from there. We're assuming this is inventory_list.php

Comment: yes,I did add name attributes to all fields.Still not working.showing 4 notices on the browser this time,saying "Notice: Undefined index: product_price",Notice: Undefined index: product_detail""Notice: Undefined index: product_division and subdivision".after that echo msg "Notice:you have added the product before".but no product on the table.Please help,if you can

Comment: and i've added enctype too.no luck.

Comment: see the latest edit. You're assigning num rows but not using the variable. if the count query is returning false, that condition will resolve to true and you will not insert. You should update the question with your revised html. undefined index will not happen if you are naming the input fields the same thing you are expecting.

Comment: I've updated the code.If you have time,can you please see the code for 1 more time,please.I would appreciate your help.Thanks for your support

Comment: You're also missing values for your options, but that shouldn't be affecting things. `<option value="food">food</option>` - aside that you should be doing things like `print_r($numrow)` above that numrow condition just to verify it actually is greater than 0. look into var_dump() and print_r() for debugging. Much of this can be done a lot easier than posting here and having us just read the code. I personally don't often commit this kind of time to a single question, especially one that keeps coming back at every step.